# How to use Let's Encrypt with Azure's API Management

Tags: azure, encryption, https, lets-encrypt, azure-api-management

I have began developing by microservices architecture utilizing Azure's API management service as the reverse proxy. To provide custom URLs for the API management, you must specify a URL + include a certificate.

[image]

I understand that there is a manual way to receive certificates through let's encrypt, but is it possible to automate this for the Azure API Management?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It isn't possible, please vote for the feature request for the API management team.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/17815891-support-for-let-s-encrypt

Some way to make it work manual:

- request certificate
- create API to prove to Letsencrypt you are the owner (domain verification)

Some way to create the certificate manual:
`sudo certbot certonly --manual`

Comment: This would be a very cool addition.  We should definitely look into this.

Comment: Could you please add more details about how to obtain a cert manually?

Comment: Here is a blog post on how to create and associate a certificate to an Azure app service using certbot and let's encrypt: https://go.azurecraftsman.com/K47Cs2

Answer (score 1):

[Key Vault Acmebot](https://github.com/shibayan/keyvault-acmebot) appears to do what you're asking. Here is an excerpt from GitHub:

> This application automates the issuance and renewal of ACME SSL/TLS certificates. The certificates are stored inside Azure Key Vault. Many Azure services such as Azure App Service, Application Gateway, CDN, etc. are able to import certificates directly from Key Vault.